# I have a website which causes IE to crash so how do I debug it?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm a little flummoxed by this. I have a live website which I've done some work on, and it works great in most browsers besides IE (which is always the case I've found). The issue is that, when trying to load the page in IE, it loads but misses some sections out. When I open the debugger to try and work out whats causing the issue - it crashes the browser then restarts it - meaning that I have no way to debug the page.

Any ideas for a) how I can debug the page and b) what could be causing the issue?

The site, for reference is cdrpumps.co.uk. There are various parts not working in IE across the site, but these are most clearly visible on the Latest Post and Case Studues sections on the homepage.

I tried to install firebug lite, but nothing kind of installed?

Is there some kind of safe mode, or something?

Answer (score 3):

To debug a website that crashes IE11.

First run IE11 in noAddons mode (iexplore.exe -extoff).

If IE still crashes in no Addons Mode, then

1. Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes.
2. Close all open IE instances and restart it. Open a blank tab. (about:blank), then display the Dev tool.
3. On the Debug tab, select "Always break on exceptions" from the dropdown (looks like a Stop Sign)
4. !important... without closing the dev tool (pin it to IE if you like), return to the blank IE page and TYPE in the address of your website. viz navigate to your site from about:blank while the dev tool is listening for errors.
5. You should see execution break in scripts with errors. Console messages will now include blocked content messages.